# Must be array type but resolved to Array_two

Tags: java

every time i type anything like this in my program i get an error right where the i and j are.  the error is the title of this question.

```
retArr[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
```

ill give you guys the beginning part of the class so you can see what im trying to do.

```
public class Array_two {
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public int[][] values;

    Array_two(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        values = new int[rows][cols];
    }

    public Array_two Add(Array_two a, Array_two b) {
        int rsz = a.rows;
        int clz = a.cols;
        int[][] retArr = new int[rsz][clz];
        for (int i = 0; i < rsz; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < clz; j++) {
                retArr[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
            }
        }
        Array_two ret = new Array_two(rsz, clz);
        ret.values = retArr;
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Java has no operator overloading, so you cannot achieve `a[i][j]` - maybe you meant `a.values[i][j]`?

Comment: So if I'm trying to manipulate and create 2d arrays how would you suggest doing that without [i][j]?

Comment: I'm trying to make this a 2d array class with different methods to double the arrays, add the arrays, print arrays etc.

Comment: He didn't say to do it without array indexes. Read the comment again.

Comment: Oh I actually only saw half of that comment lol sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

`[]` syntax can only be used with arrays. `Array_two` is not an array type, so `[]` cannot be used.

I think you meant

```
ret[i][j] = a.values[i][j] + b.values[i][j];
```

`values` *is* an array, so you can access its elements with `[]`.

Other tips:

You should probably not make all your fields public. Create getters and setters.

Classes are named with `PascalCase`, so `ArrayTwo`, not `Array_two`.

Methods are named with `camelCase`, so `add`, not `Add`.

The `Add` method should probably be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use as below:
public class Array_two {
    public int rows;
    public int cols;
    public int[][] values;

    Array_two(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        values = new int[rows][cols];
    }

    public Array_two Add(Array_two a, Array_two b) {
        int rsz = a.rows;
        int clz = a.cols;
        int[][] retArr = new int[rsz][clz];
        for (int i = 0; i < rsz; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < clz; j++) {
                retArr[i][j] = a.values[i][j] + b.values[i][j];
            }
        }
        Array_two ret = new Array_two(rsz, clz);
        ret.values = retArr;
        return ret;
    }}
```

Comment: You would be better off explaining what you had changed so the author (and future readers) of the question can understand what the underlying issue is.